# is it safe to use the same mutex with lock_gard and without it in other parts of code

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, mutex, raii

I have the namespace below which func1 and func2 will be called from diffrent threads.

```
#include<thread>
namespace test{

    std::mutex mu;

    void func1(){
        std::lock_guard<mutex>lock(mu);
       //the whole function needs to be protected
    }

    void func2() {
        mu.lock();
        //some code that should not be executed when func1 is executed
        mu.unlock();
        //some other code
    }
}
```

is it deadlock safe to use this mutex (once with lock_guard and outside of it ) to protect these critical sections ? if not how to achieve this logic?

Comment: Just to be clear, the `mutex` instance is what matters.  The `lock_guard` merely is a convenient way of locking and unlocking the `mutex`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can effectively mix and match different guard instances (e.g. lock_guard, unique_lock, etc...) with `std::mutex` in different functions.  One case I run into occassionally is when I want to use `std::lock_guard` for most methods, but usage of  `std::condition_variable` expects a `std::unique_lock` for its `wait` method.

To elaborate on what Oblivion said, I typically introduce a new scope block within a function so that usage of `std::lock_guard` is consistent.  Example:

```
void func2() {

    {  // ENTER LOCK
        lock_guard<std::mutex> lck;

       //some code that should not be executed when func1 is executed

    } // EXIT LOCK

    // some other (thread safe) code 
}
```

The advantage of the using the above pattern is that if anything throws an exception within the critical section of code that is under a lock, the destructor of `lck` will still be invoked and hence, unlock the mutex.

Answer (score 3):

Everything the `lock_guard` does is to guarantee unlock on destruction. It's a convenience to get code right when functions can take multiple paths (think of exceptions!) not a necessity. Also, it builds on the "regular" `lock()` and `unlock()` functions. In summary, it is safe.

Answer (score 2):

Deadlock happens when at least two `mutex` are involved or the single `mutex` didn't unlock forever for whatever reason.

The only issue with the second function is, in case of exception the lock will not be released.

You can simply use `lock_guard` or anything else that gets destroyed(and unlocks the mutex at dtor) to avoid such a scenario as you did for the first function.